# source .bashrc doesn't work

Tags: bashrc

I installed TinyOS on RedHat for my academic purposes. Now I can't log in to the system.
I logged in in single user mode.

Then I tried to log in.
I couldn't login in as any user.
I couldn't start the X server manually (the system doesn't start the X server when it boots up).

Then I execute these commands

```
sh# hostname
```

(none)

```
sh# source .bashrc
```

bash-: gives a path relevant to TinyOS and says unable to find it

actually there is no such a file.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

On some systems .bash_rc is replaced by .profile . I don't know wether it's true for your system.

Answer (score 0):

I have TinyOS installed too and I put the call to the initialization script in the /etc/profile and all work well.